# Is it a way to use Next.js and WordPress pages under the same domain?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js

I have a Next.js site, but for the Landing page I would use a WordPress site. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

In the `next.config.js`, you can set `rewrites` to work like a proxy with specific application paths. If you want only NextJS homepage router to another domain homepage, you can do this:

```
module.exports = {
  rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "http://mywordpresssite.com/",
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

[Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/incremental-adoption)

Comment: And what will happen with the domain, it will change to a different one? I guess next.js is not under mywordpresssite.com, right?

Comment: The main domain keep showing all routes from Next app, but the home in Next app show the content from `http://mywordpresssite.com/` inside Next app domain.

Comment: a, ok, home route show the content, but does not loads `mywordpresssite.com` into browser address bar, right?

Comment: Do you think it is possible to load only subpart of the page form WordPress, use menu form Next.js, but load content from WordPress site

Comment: Unfortunatelly the domain changes. I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Everything depends on the hosting server that you will use for hosting those website's. You can use one domain for both but you might be forced to use different route's.

Example:

Landing Page : `www.example.com` or `www.example.com/home`

Wordpress : `www.example.com/news`

Using apache for hosting, you can define a .htaccess that would redirect to the right application depending on the route.
I would suggest you to look into that, unless you can provide us more details about your hosting solution.

Edit:
You can check out the vercel configuration file to route something to specific subfolder/files.
More info here: https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/redirects

Comment: I am using Vercel.